# Developing android client app to use BigBlueButton server

Tags: android, bigbluebutton

I dont know if there is anybody who have started to integrate the BigBlueButton

http://demo.bigbluebutton.org/ 
A video conferencing application for android. I've started developing a simple app, which opens the installed BBB-android application from my application. I am using

```
Uri ServerUrl = Uri.parse("bigbluebutton://api/create?name=Android&meetingID=TestBBB&checksum=5cacecd62666d26c051ac2846fdd37e1bb6bebaa");
```

But its not working. As soon as application opens, it shows "Can't Join the meeting". Can anyone please diagnose this and reply for the same as soon as possible??
Regards..

Comment: Diagnosing problems is what you have to do before asking here. A good question should be answerable with just reading your problem description and not by creating an app to test things for you.

Comment: I meant if anybody has already deployed BBB-android app on his emulator, and possibly have came across the aforesaid problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this if you have `your_ip`:

```
Uri ServerUrl = Uri.parse("http://YOUR_IP/bigbluebutton/api/join?meetingID=fds%27s+meeting&fullName=fds&password=mp&checksum=50b6dcfe7111163a868e301c8efae03898de3a2f");
```

Comment: Can Anyone give me a sample code link for BigBlueButton Android Studio Project.